# How to By Pass Face Detection Functionality in Selenium Automation?

Tags: java, selenium, automation, selenium-chromedriver

We have a web app, When we click on "Take Selfie button" it is redirected us to next page.
On the next page, first it is detecting the face and than it is loading the filters.

Now, I am automating the testing of this functionality in Selenium Java, TestNG. but in automated browser, face is not detected and text case script can't proceed.

My Question: Is there any way, we can bypass the face detection and directly go to next step?

Note: Without detecting the face, the next options are not loading.

Answer (score 0):

**There are two solutions to your problem:**

1. You can ask your dev team to provide you with some bypass mechanism for the same.
2. You can use fake media and try to inject that media into the webcam. For this, you need to pass three arguments as mentioned below.

//Configure ChromeOptions to pass a fake media stream

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--use-fake-device-for-media-stream");
options.addArguments("--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream");
options.addArguments("--use-file-for-fake-video-capture=Johnny_1280x720_60.y4m");

 WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

**Arguments:**

1. **--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream** = Bypass the media stream infobar by selecting the default device for media streams.
2. **--use-fake-device-for-media-stream =** Use fake device for Media Stream
   to replace the actual camera and microphone.
3. **--use-file-for-fake-video-capture** = Use an .y4m file to play as the
   webcam.

I downloaded y4m here http://media.xiph.org/video/derf/y4m/

**Output:**

[image]